# 90s(?) horror movie with two couples in a faraway house, a beheaded bride trying to kill her husband, and having to read a paper to chase the ghosts

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Two newly married couples went to a faraway house. They were chased by something that killed the bride. He went back alone to the house, where his wife, with her head cut off, suddenly appeared and tried to kill him.

After a while, some friends came and realized the house is haunted. They had to read some papers to make the ghosts get out of the house, but when anyone started reading, the ghosts would come and try to kill the reader.

I can't remember the name of the movie, but it is an old one, maybe from the 1990s.

Comment: Sounds vaguely Evil-Deadish (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Evil_Dead). Perhaps a cheap knockoff?

Answer (score 7):

This is [*Evil Dead II*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092991/) (1987) - a semi-sequel/remake of *Evil Dead*.

> Ash and his girlfriend Linda are in a remote cabin in the woods. There he discovers a tape recorder that a professor had used to record incantations from the Necronomicon XMortis - the Book of the Dead. When he turns it on, the recording releases a dark, sinister force from the woods. It turns Linda into a zombie, her soul possessed by some hideous demon, and then tries to do the same to Ash. Other people come to help Ash, but one by one they are taken over by the Evil Dead force that also possesses Linda, the Professor, and the Professor's wife...and they try to make sure Ash is...Dead by Dawn!